# Native Query throws InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a native query in Spring Boot, but unfortunately it throws an exception.

This is my method:

```
@Override
public List<Classification> doFuzzySearch(String search) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM `classification` WHERE SOUNDEX(`data`) LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('(?1)'), 2), '%')", Classification.class);
    query.setParameter(1, search);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The query runs without any problems in MySQL, but in Spring it throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I changed `?1` to `?0`, but that didn't work. Hopefully somebody knows what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Try try just `?` without any number

Comment: @StanislavL I just tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: What about `SOUNDEX(?)` ?

Comment: @StanislavL Omg, you're my hero! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should be

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM `classification`  +
     "WHERE SOUNDEX(`data`) LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX(?'), 2), '%')",
      Classification.class);
```

The reason is the param does not need the to be wrapped into `' '`. Also just natural order is used. No need to provide `?1`